# AngularJS Typescript Controller Values not updating page

Tags: angularjs, typescript, service, controller

I'm picking up Angular for the first time and coming from a .NET backround feel a lot more comfortable working with typescript.

I've got a problem where a cant seem to get values to update on a page when a controller populates the controller values with an object received from a service. I'm probably just making a noob error.

Can anyone give a pointer on what I'm doing wrong.

So my typescript is

```
module ConnectAdmin.Interfaces {
    export interface ITemplate {
        templateId: number;
        name: string;
        description: string;
    }
}

module ConnectAdmin.Interfaces {
    export interface ITemplateCollection {
        total: number;
        set: number;
        skipped: number;
        collection: Array<ITemplate>;
    }
}

module ConnectAdmin.Controllers {
    import TemplateCollection = Interfaces.ITemplateCollection;

    export class TemplateIndexController {
        static $inject = ["ConnectAdmin.Services.TemplateService"];

        constructor(templateService: ConnectAdmin.Services.TemplateService) {
            this.defaultTemplates = { skipped: 0, set: 0, total: 0, collection: [] };
            this.templates = this.defaultTemplates;
            this.processing = true;
            this.store = this;

            templateService.index(this.take, this.skip, this.successCallback, this.errorCallback);

            this.processing = false;
        }

        successCallback(data: TemplateCollection) {
            this.templates = { skipped: 0, set: 0, total: 0, collection: [] }
            this.templates = data;
            alert(this.templates.collection.length);
        }

        errorCallback(response: any) {
            this.templates = this.defaultTemplates;
            alert(response.status);
            this.message = "An Error Occurred Contacting the API";
        }

        processing: boolean;

        store = this;

        defaultTemplates: TemplateCollection;
        templates: TemplateCollection;

        take = 20;
        skip = 0;
        message: string;
    }

    angular.module("ConnectAdmin").controller("ConnectAdmin.Controllers.TemplateIndexController", TemplateIndexController);
}

module ConnectAdmin.Services {
    import TemplateCollection = Interfaces.ITemplateCollection;
    import TemplateIndexController = Controllers.TemplateIndexController;

    export class TemplateService {
        constructor($http: ng.IHttpService) {
            this.http = $http;
        }

        http: ng.IHttpService;

        index(take: number, skip: number, successCallback: Function, errorCallback: Function) {
            const req = {
                method: "GET",
                url: "https://localhost:44336/api/Templates?take=" + take + "&skip=" + skip,
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                }
            };

            this.http(req).then(response => {
                    successCallback(response.data);
                },
                response => {
                    errorCallback(response);
                });

            //return { total: 1, skipped: 0, set: 1, collection: [{ templateId: 1, name: "Template 1", description: "" }] };
        }
    }

    angular.module("ConnectAdmin").service("ConnectAdmin.Services.TemplateService", TemplateService);
}
```

with my html being:

```
<div id="template-index">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="info-box">
            <div class="info-box-title">
                Templates
            </div>
            <div class="info-box-content" ng-controller="ConnectAdmin.Controllers.TemplateIndexController as templateCtrl">
                <table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>#</td>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>Description</td>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr class="tr-select" ng-click="templateCtrl.openTemplate(template.templateId)" ng-repeat="template in templateCtrl.templates.collection">
                        <td>{{template.templateId}}</td>
                        <td>{{template.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{template.description}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div id="template-index-loader" class="loader" ng-show="templateCtrl.processing"></div>
                <div class="info-box-footnote" ng-hide="templateCtrl.templates.collection.length">
                    Displaying {{templateCtrl.templates.skipped + 1}} to {{templateCtrl.templates.set + templateCtrl.templates.skipped}} of {{templateCtrl.templates.total}}
                </div>
                <div class="info-box-footnote" ng-show="templateCtrl.message.length">
                    {{templateCtrl.message}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't think its the http call as I get no update if I return a hardcoded object.

The alert in the success callback gives me a correct value.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that your scope is being changed in your success callback. Try using your controller scope you defined in your constructor like this

```
successCallback(data: TemplateCollection) {
        store.templates = { skipped: 0, set: 0, total: 0, collection: [] }
        store.templates = data;
        alert(store.templates.collection.length);
    }
```

Otherwise I think when you say, "this" you're referring to the scope of the successCallback function

Answer (score 0):

Ah great! Thanks, you put me on the right track.

Doing the update you said I was getting intellisense promts to say do you mean this.store which had the same outcome.

Following on from that and doing a bit of digging yes all the variables were undefined.

I've updated the Controller and Service to be:

```
    module ConnectAdmin.Controllers {
    import TemplateCollection = Interfaces.ITemplateCollection;

    export interface ITemplateIndexScope extends ng.IScope {
        vm: any;
    }

    export class TemplateIndexController {
        static $inject = ["ConnectAdmin.Services.TemplateService"];

        constructor(templateService: ConnectAdmin.Services.TemplateService) {            
            this.templates = { skipped: 0, set: 0, total: 0, collection: [] };                        
            this.templateService = templateService;
            this.take = 20;
            this.skip = 0;
            this.refresh();
        }

        refresh() {
            this.processing = true;
            this.templateService.index(this.take, this.skip, this);            
        }

        successCallback(data: TemplateCollection) {                        
            this.templates = data;            
            alert(this.templates.collection.length);
            this.processing = false;
        }

        errorCallback(response: any) {
            this.templates = { skipped: 0, set: 0, total: 0, collection: [] };
            alert(response.status);
            this.message = "An Error Occurred Contacting the API";
            this.processing = false;
        }

        processing: boolean;
        templates: TemplateCollection;
        take: number;
        skip: number;
        message: string;
        templateService: Services.TemplateService;
    }

    angular.module("ConnectAdmin").controller("ConnectAdmin.Controllers.TemplateIndexController", TemplateIndexController);
}

module ConnectAdmin.Services {
    import TemplateCollection = Interfaces.ITemplateCollection;
    import TemplateIndexController = Controllers.TemplateIndexController;

    export class TemplateService {
        constructor($http: ng.IHttpService) {
            this.http = $http;
        }

        http: ng.IHttpService;

        index(take: number, skip: number, templateController: TemplateIndexController) {
            const req = {
                method: "GET",
                url: "https://localhost:44336/api/Templates?take=" + take + "&skip=" + skip,
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                }
            };

            this.http(req).then(response => {
                    var data = response.data as TemplateCollection;
                    templateController.successCallback(data);
                },
                response => {
                    templateController.errorCallback(response);
                });
        }
    }

    angular.module("ConnectAdmin").service("ConnectAdmin.Services.TemplateService", TemplateService);
}
```

So I'm passing the instance of the controller into the service rather than the callback functions.

Cheers